# Measuring CO2 concentration from a respiration chamber

Tags: measurements

I am interested in measuring the concentration of CO2 from an open circuit respiration chamber where a sheep is living.

Known variables:

- Concentration of CO2 of the air entering the chamber.
- Concentration of CO2 of the air leaving the chamber. 
   Note. These concentrations were carried out after the CO2 analyzer removed any water vapour from the sample coming from the chamber
  .
- Altitude, atmospheric pressure.
- Temperature and humidity of the air leaving the chamber.
- Flow rate at which the air leaves the chamber.

Not being a physicist I would appreciate you tell me the equations needed rather than pointing me in vague direction.

Much appreciated.

Javier

Comment: I'm confused. You say that you're looking to measure the concentration of $\text{CO}_2$ from the respiration chamber, but then you list concentration of $\text{CO}_2$ of air leaving the chamber as a known quantity.

Comment: Perhaps you are trying to find the rate at which the sheep generates CO2?